# Can anyone provide an approachable explanation of how an edge-preserving smooth works?

Tags: algorithm, image, language-agnostic

How does an edge preserving smooth work? This is an image filter which blurs the image without messing up the edges.

My searches on Google have turned up only academic papers discussing mathematics that are way beyond my comprehension.

Can you provide some pseudocode or a link to a simple explanation?

Comment: Probably operates similarly (or oppositely) to how edge sharpening filters work in regards to edge detection.

Comment: It depends on the algorithm. Do you have a name of a specific one you're interested in ?

Comment: @Yochai Timmer- No. Is there a simple proto-algorithm which the specific implementations are based on? Is there any one in particular which you are familiar with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there's a lot of math in doing that, so if you don't understand the mathematical equations you found, I'll try to explain it in simple terms:

[Smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing) in general is done by doing some kind weighted average of the adjacent pixels.

Because this is basically math, and pictures are basically 3D matrices, you can achieve [smoothing](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/Smoothing_an_Image.html) efficiently with basic matrix mathematical manipulations.

Now to get [edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) you just need to find the difference between adjacent pixels (or if it's a wide edge, you can set a maximal width), which again is just the [gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of the matrix. (Multi-dimensial Derivative).

So, even if you do it naively, you could use the gradient as a weight factor for the weighting the average of pixel color.

I assume that most of the mathematical equations you'll find use the gradient at some level, but just make it more efficient (single mathematical formula in oppose to many loops)

Comment: I've learned that both blurring and edge detection can be done with a convolution matrix. http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-convmatrix.html So is an edge preserving smooth a convolution matrix operation which uses the sum of the blurring kernel and the edge detection kernel?

Comment: Convolution will give you a nice representation of the difference between two functions, which you could apply to give you the difference between the original picture and the gradient (or some other measurement). It's just a tool. There are a lot of methods to do this, some are better some are worse. Every other person who wants a high degree in CS and image processing comes up with a new mathematical equation for this.

Comment: Convolution, or **any linear filter**, will be very destructive to edges, either blurring them out or adding ringing (likely a mix of both). Median filter will avoid this, but it's rather too discrete for good "smoothing".

Answer (score 0):

If you take a really simple 2D smoothing filter (like a box or Gaussian kernel) this will smooth in all directions about equally (more true for Gaussian than box.)   The basic idea is somehow making a filter that smooths parallel to the edge (or along it), but not perpendicular to it (or across it), as much as possible.

However, you don't know *a priori* which direction the edge is for any given point in the image, so you have to figure this out.  What most edge-preserving smoothings wind up doing is computing which direction the edge is locally, and then applying the appropriate smoothing direction.   Some do these two steps more explicitly, and some just wind up rolling all of that math into one.

Answer (score 0):

The median filter might help you, since it tends to keep edges in images both sharp and in place while removing outlying noise. It works by replacing every pixel with the median pixel in its neighborhood, i.e. the pixel that would be the middle one if you would sort the neighborhood pixels by value.